# Show div with jQuery if a URL parameter is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have these divs set up on all my pages to catch if the action was a success or not through a URL parameter. The error div is supposed to show when there's an error - and the success div, when it's a success.

It seems to work fine on other pages, except this one. I've gone through it several times and can't figure out what might be wrong.

In firebug console, I get this: 
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$('#action-success').show();

CSS:

```
    /* error div */
    div#action-error
    {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid white;
        display: none;
        background-color: #a80077;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }

    /* success div */
    div#action-success
    {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid white;
        display: none;
        background-color: #5a8e4a;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <!-- RESULT ERROR/SUCCESS -->
    <div class="container_12" id="action-error">
        <span class="error">Error: There was an error deleting your album. Please try again.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container_12" id="action-success">
       <span class="success">Your album was deleted successfully.</span>
    </div>
    <!-- RESULT ERROR/SUCCESS END -->
```

Jquery:

Top of page: (found on SO)

```
        <script>
            function getParameterByName(name) {
                return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
            }
        </script>
```

Bottom:

```
        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        var error = getParameterByName('error');

        if(error){
            alert(error);
            $('#action-error').show();
        }
       //------------------------------------------------------------------
        var success = getParameterByName('result');

        if(success){
            $('#action-success').show();
        }
```

I've looked at the other topics on SO, but none of them seem to be exactly what my issue is. Any help would be appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post any JS errors logged on your debug console (Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Firebug)?

Comment: in the console, I get this: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$('#action-success').show();

Comment: jQuery must not be included or may be included multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, folks - this is what happens when you code half-asleep going on coffee fumes. The problem was I forgot to include the jQuery library in my file... Sorry to have wasted your time.

I'm working on my dunce cap as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped the JavaScript with a function that passes jQuery as $?

```
(function($){
    //-----------
    var error = getParameterByName('error');

    if(error){
        alert(error);
        $('#action-error').show();
    }
   //------------------------------------------------------------------
    var success = getParameterByName('result');

    if(success){
        $('#action-success').show();
    }
    //------------

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Its kinda silly to doubt this, but i still am asking - the JavaScript that has `$("#action-success").show()` - it should be called inside a function that looks like above. Otherwise, the $ variable is not defined as jQuery. So if you are using jQuery $, you should have a wrapper function around all that code.

Comment: Modified. Add that wrapper and try.

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Any idea why it works on all my other pages, as is?